# Can the Master Ball be traded as a held item?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I have just got the expansion pass for Crown Tundra, and am wondering if it's possible to trade master balls to my main game in order to guarantee I catch legendary pokémon on the Dynamax Adventures.

If I play through the main story on my second cartridge up until I get the master ball, can I trade it to my main cartridge as a held item on a pokémon? Would it also work through Pokémon HOME so I don't have to use another console?

Answer (score 9):

The Master Ball is a regular item and can be traded by letting a Pokémon hold it, but like any other held item it can't be transferred through Pokémon Home. However, it's not necessary to get more Master Balls to accomplish your goal, as the legendary Pokémon at the end of a Dynamax Adventure is guaranteed to be caught no matter what Poké Ball you're using.

> Every Pokémon defeated during a Dynamax Adventure can be caught without fail, but only one Pokémon can be kept from each adventure.
>
> - [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Dynamax_Adventure)

Comment: It might be good to note that you can only catch each legendary or ultra beast once. If the OP is wanting to farm for shinies or best nature, it’s best not to choose it